# how to get a subgroup start finish indexes of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"C1":['USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','JAPAN','JAPAN','JAPAN','USA','USA'],'C2':['A','B','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','A']})

    C1      C2
0   USA     A
1   USA     B
2   USA     A
3   USA     A
4   USA     A
5   JAPAN   A
6   JAPAN   A
7   JAPAN   A
8   USA     B
9   USA     A
```

This is a watered version of my problem so to keep it simple, my objective is to iterate a sub group of the dataframe where C2 has B in it. If a B is in C2 - I look at C1 and need the entire group. So in this example, I see USA and it starts at index 0 and finish at 4. Another one is between 8 and 9.

So my desired result would be the indexes such that:

```
[[0,4],[8,9]]
```

I tried to use groupby but it wouldn't work because it groups all the USA together

```
my_index = list(df[df['C2']=='B'].index)
my_index
```

woudld give 1,8 but how to get the start/finish?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one approach where you can first mask the dataframe on groups which has atleast 1 `B`, then grab the index and create a helper column to aggregate the first and last index values:

```
s = df['C1'].ne(df['C1'].shift()).cumsum()
i = df.index[s.isin(s[df['C2'].eq("B")])]
p = np.where(np.diff(i)>1)[0]+1
split_ = np.split(i,p)
out = [[i[0],i[-1]] for i in split_]
```

---

```
print(out)
[[0, 4], [8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach using [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html).

```
# Keep all the indexes needed 
temp = df['C1'].ne(df['C1'].shift()).cumsum()
stored_index = df.index[temp.isin(temp[df['C2'].eq("B")])]

# Group the list based on consecutive numbers
import more_itertools as mit
out = [list(i) for i in mit.consecutive_groups(stored_index)]

# Get first and last elements from the nested (grouped) lists
final = [a[:1] + a[-1:] for a in out]
```

---

```
>>> print(final)
[[0, 4], [8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Solution

```
b = df['C1'].ne(df['C1'].shift()).cumsum()
m = b.isin(b[df['C2'].eq('B')])
i = m.index[m].to_series().groupby(b).agg(['first', 'last']).values.squeeze()
```

#### Explanations

`shift` column `C1` and comapre the shifted column with the non-shifted one to create a boolean mask then take a `cumulative` sum on this mask to identify the blocks of rows where the value in column `C1` stays the same

```
>>> b

0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    2
6    2
7    2
8    3
9    3
Name: C1, dtype: int64
```

Create a boolean mask `m` to identify the blocks of rows that contain at least on `B`

```
>>> m

0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
8     True
9     True
Name: C1, dtype: bool
```

Filter the `index` by using boolean masking with mask `m`, then `group` the filtered index by the identified blocks `b` and aggregate using `first` and `last` to get the indices.

```
>>> i

array([[0, 4],
       [8, 9]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Another version:

```
x = (
    df.groupby((df.C1 != df.C1.shift(1)).cumsum())["C2"]
    .apply(lambda x: [x.index[0], x.index[-1]] if ("B" in x.values) else np.nan)
    .dropna()
    .to_list()
)

print(x)
```

Prints:

```
[[0, 4], [8, 9]]
```